# how use aws profile when using ansible ec2.py module

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I wrote a quick ansible playbook to launch a simple ec2 instance but I think I have an issue on how I want to authenticate.

What I don't want to do is set my aws access/secret keys as env variables since they expire each hour and I need to regenerate the `~/.aws/credentials` file via a script.

Right now, my ansible playbook looks like this:

```
--- # Launch ec2
- name: Create ec2 instance
  hosts: local
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    profile: profile_xxxx
    key_pair: usrxxx
    region: us-east-1
    subnet: subnet-38xxxxx
    security_groups: ['sg-e54xxxx', 'sg-bfcxxxx', 'sg-a9dxxx']
    image: ami-031xxx
    instance_type: t2.small
    num_instances: 1
    tag_name: ansibletest
    hdd_volumes:
    - device_name: /dev/sdf
      volume_size: 50
      delete_on_termination: true
    - device_name: /dev/sdh
      volume_size: 50
      delete_on_termination: true
  tasks:
    - name: launch ec2
      ec2:
        count: 1
        key_name: "{{ key_pair }}"
        profile: "{{ profile }}"
        group_id: "{{ security_groups }}"
        instance_type: "{{ instance_type }}"
        image: "{{ image }}"
        region: "{{ region }}"
        vpc_subnet_id: "{{ subnet }}"
        assign_public_ip: false
        volumes: "{{ hdd_volumes }}"
        instance_tags:
          Name: "{{ tag_name }}"
          ASV: "{{ tag_asv }}"
          CMDBEnvironment: "{{ tag_cmdbEnv }}"
          EID: "{{ tag_eid }}"
          OwnerContact: "{{ tag_eid }}"
      register: ec2
    - name: print ec2 vars
      debug: var=ec
```

my hosts file is this:

```
[local]
localhost ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/python2.7
```

I run my playbook like this:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts launchec2.yml -vvv
```

and then get this back:

```
PLAYBOOK: launchec2.yml ********************************************************
1 plays in launchec2.yml

PLAY [Create ec2 instance] *****************************************************

TASK [launch ec2] **************************************************************
task path: /Users/usrxxx/Desktop/cloud-jumper/Ansible/launchec2.yml:27
Using module file /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/core/cloud/amazon/ec2.py
<localhost> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: usrxxx
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1485527483.82-106272618422730 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1485527483.82-106272618422730="` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1485527483.82-106272618422730 `" ) && sleep 0'
<localhost> PUT /var/folders/cx/_fdv7nkn6dz21798p_bn9dp9ln9sqc/T/tmpnk2rh5 TO /Users/usrxxx/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1485527483.82-106272618422730/ec2.py
<localhost> PUT /var/folders/cx/_fdv7nkn6dz21798p_bn9dp9ln9sqc/T/tmpEpwenH TO /Users/usrxxx/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1485527483.82-106272618422730/args
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /Users/usrxxx/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1485527483.82-106272618422730/ /Users/usrxxx/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1485527483.82-106272618422730/ec2.py /Users/usrxxx/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1485527483.82-106272618422730/args && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/env python /Users/usrxxx/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1485527483.82-106272618422730/ec2.py /Users/usrxxx/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1485527483.82-106272618422730/args; rm -rf "/Users/usrxxx/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1485527483.82-106272618422730/" > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "failed": true, 
    "invocation": {
        "module_name": "ec2"
    }, 
    "module_stderr": "usage: ec2.py [-h] [--list] [--host HOST] [--refresh-cache]\n              [--profile BOTO_PROFILE]\nec2.py: error: unrecognized arguments: /Users/usrxxx/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1485527483.82-106272618422730/args\n", 
    "module_stdout": "", 
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE"
}
    to retry, use: --limit @/Users/usrxxx/Desktop/cloud-jumper/Ansible/launchec2.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

I noticed in the `ec2.py` file it says this:

```
NOTE: This script assumes Ansible is being executed where the environment
variables needed for Boto have already been set:
    export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='AK123'
    export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='abc123'

This script also assumes there is an ec2.ini file alongside it.  To specify a
different path to ec2.ini, define the EC2_INI_PATH environment variable:

    export EC2_INI_PATH=/path/to/my_ec2.ini

If you're using eucalyptus you need to set the above variables and
you need to define:

    export EC2_URL=http://hostname_of_your_cc:port/services/Eucalyptus

If you're using boto profiles (requires boto>=2.24.0) you can choose a profile
using the --boto-profile command line argument (e.g. ec2.py --boto-profile prod) or using
the AWS_PROFILE variable:

    AWS_PROFILE=prod ansible-playbook -i ec2.py myplaybook.yml
```

so I ran it like this:

```
AWS_PROFILE=profile_xxxx ansible-playbook -i hosts launchec2.yml -vvv
```

but still got the same results...

----EDIT-----

I also ran it like this:

```
export ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=false
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY=<your aws access key here>
export AWS_SECRET_KEY=<your aws secret key here>

ansible-playbook -i hosts launchec2.yml
```

but still got this back...still seems to be a credentials issue?

```
usrxxx$ ansible-playbook -i hosts launchec2.yml 

PLAY [Create ec2 instance] *****************************************************

TASK [launch ec2] **************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "usage: ec2.py [-h] [--list] [--host HOST] [--refresh-cache]\n              [--profile BOTO_PROFILE]\nec2.py: error: unrecognized arguments: /Users/usrxxx/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1485531356.01-33528208838066/args\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE"}
    to retry, use: --limit @/Users/usrxxx/Desktop/cloud-jumper/Ansible/launchec2.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

---EDIT 2------

Completely removed ansible and then installed with homebrew but got the same error....so I think went to the directory that its looking for ec2.py (`Using module file /usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.2.1.0/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/core/cloud/amazon/ec2.py`) and replaced that ec2.py with this one...https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/devel/contrib/inventory/ec2.py....but now get this error:

```
Using /Users/usrxxx/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file

PLAYBOOK: launchec2.yml ********************************************************
1 plays in launchec2.yml

PLAY [Create ec2 instance] *****************************************************

TASK [aws : launch ec2] ********************************************************
task path: /Users/usrxxx/Desktop/cloud-jumper/Ansible/roles/aws/tasks/main.yml:1
Using module file /usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.2.1.0/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/core/cloud/amazon/ec2.py
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "failed": true, 
    "msg": "module (ec2) is missing interpreter line"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have placed `ec2.py` [inventory script](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#example-aws-ec2-external-inventory-script) into your `/path/to/playbook/library/` folder.
You should not put dynamic inventory scripts there – this way Ansible runs inventory script instead of [ec2 module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_module.html).

Remove ec2.py from your project's library folder (or Ansible global [library](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#library) defined in ansible.cfg) and try again.

Comment: I don't have the ec2.py or ec2.ini files in my playbook path...isn't it looking in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/core/cloud/amazon/` for the ec2.py module?

Comment: You may have placed it somewhere else in library search path. Try your playbook from clean VM. Ansible will take ec2.py from default path if there is no ec2.py in other places available (this logic is very useful to override default modules). Your output suggests that you run inventory script instead of ec2 module.

Comment: I completely removed ansible and install it again via homebrew but still get the same error...

Comment: I replaced the ec2.py with the one in the link but now get a different error...made an edit 2 to show it...

Comment: OMG... please read my original answer word by word – it's all you need. Make clean project directory with empty `ansible.cfg` and add lines of code one by one. I'm out of this thread, sorry.

Comment: No inventory script (or the ec2 modules) in my `/path/to/playbook/library/` folder. My ansible.cfg file is only defining where my pem file is and what user to use (`ec2-user`). this is where I'm confused...the only place where ec2.py exists is in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python‌​2.7/site-packages/an‌​sible/modules/core/c‌​loud/amazon/`...no where else does it exists...if I remove it from there, it can't find the ec2 module then when the playbook runes...I've reinstalled it but still no luck, and I've followed what you stated above after I did the reinstall